# weather-js extracting specific data from what is printed

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using [weather-js](https://github.com/devfacet/weather) to gather weather data for a users location that is determined by their IP address. I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the data printed out in the console. This api has no docs or explanations besides its main function "weather.find" here is what I have:

```js
 weather2.find({search: location, degreeType: 'F'}, function(result, current) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
      });
```

location is a predetermined variable pulled from a DB, and here is what is printed out,

```js
[
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "Larchmont, NY",
      "lat": "40.928",
      "long": "-73.751",
      "timezone": "-4",
      "alert": "",
      "degreetype": "F",
      "imagerelativeurl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"
    },
    "current": {
      "temperature": "78",
      "skycode": "34",
      "skytext": "Mostly Sunny",
      "date": "2018-07-29",
      "observationtime": "11:45:00",
      "observationpoint": "Larchmont, NY",
      "feelslike": "78",
      "humidity": "62",
      "winddisplay": "5 mph Northwest",
      "day": "Sunday",
      "shortday": "Sun",
      "windspeed": "5 mph",
      "imageUrl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/34.gif"
    },
    "forecast": [
      {
        "low": "68",
        "high": "85",
        "skycodeday": "31",
        "skytextday": "Mostly Clear",
        "date": "2018-07-28",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "shortday": "Sat",
        "precip": ""
      },
      {
        "low": "73",
        "high": "85",
        "skycodeday": "30",
        "skytextday": "Partly Sunny",
        "date": "2018-07-29",
        "day": "Sunday",
        "shortday": "Sun",
        "precip": "0"
      },
      {
        "low": "74",
        "high": "84",
        "skycodeday": "28",
        "skytextday": "Mostly Cloudy",
        "date": "2018-07-30",
        "day": "Monday",
        "shortday": "Mon",
        "precip": "10"
      },
      {
        "low": "76",
        "high": "82",
        "skycodeday": "9",
        "skytextday": "Light Rain",
        "date": "2018-07-31",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "shortday": "Tue",
        "precip": "80"
      },
      {
        "low": "79",
        "high": "86",
        "skycodeday": "4",
        "skytextday": "T-Storms",
        "date": "2018-08-01",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "shortday": "Wed",
        "precip": "100"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

any assistance on how to pull out specific data points like the current temperature from this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Either you are not sure what exactly you are looking for, or you just want us to code for you. Anyways, you can try writing a function for this that takes data and the names of the values that you want to pull out from that data.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` is a javascript array containing objects. The array has one element at index zero. So to access information, you just need to use the index and the property names:

```js
let result  = [{"location": {"name": "Larchmont, NY","lat": "40.928","long": "-73.751","timezone": "-4","alert": "","degreetype": "F","imagerelativeurl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"},"current": {"temperature": "78","skycode": "34","skytext": "Mostly Sunny","date": "2018-07-29","observationtime": "11:45:00","observationpoint": "Larchmont, NY","feelslike": "78","humidity": "62","winddisplay": "5 mph Northwest","day": "Sunday","shortday": "Sun","windspeed": "5 mph","imageUrl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/34.gif"},"forecast": [{"low": "68","high": "85","skycodeday": "31","skytextday": "Mostly Clear","date": "2018-07-28","day": "Saturday","shortday": "Sat","precip": ""},{"low": "73","high": "85","skycodeday": "30","skytextday": "Partly Sunny","date": "2018-07-29","day": "Sunday","shortday": "Sun","precip": "0"},{"low": "74","high": "84","skycodeday": "28","skytextday": "Mostly Cloudy","date": "2018-07-30","day": "Monday","shortday": "Mon","precip": "10"},{"low": "76","high": "82","skycodeday": "9","skytextday": "Light Rain","date": "2018-07-31","day": "Tuesday","shortday": "Tue","precip": "80"},{"low": "79","high": "86","skycodeday": "4","skytextday": "T-Storms","date": "2018-08-01","day": "Wednesday","shortday": "Wed","precip": "100"}]}]

console.log(result[0].current.temperature)
console.log(result[0].location.name)
```

The forecast property is also an array. You can loop through that to get individual days:

```js
let result  = [{"location": {"name": "Larchmont, NY","lat": "40.928","long": "-73.751","timezone": "-4","alert": "","degreetype": "F","imagerelativeurl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"},"current": {"temperature": "78","skycode": "34","skytext": "Mostly Sunny","date": "2018-07-29","observationtime": "11:45:00","observationpoint": "Larchmont, NY","feelslike": "78","humidity": "62","winddisplay": "5 mph Northwest","day": "Sunday","shortday": "Sun","windspeed": "5 mph","imageUrl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/34.gif"},"forecast": [{"low": "68","high": "85","skycodeday": "31","skytextday": "Mostly Clear","date": "2018-07-28","day": "Saturday","shortday": "Sat","precip": ""},{"low": "73","high": "85","skycodeday": "30","skytextday": "Partly Sunny","date": "2018-07-29","day": "Sunday","shortday": "Sun","precip": "0"},{"low": "74","high": "84","skycodeday": "28","skytextday": "Mostly Cloudy","date": "2018-07-30","day": "Monday","shortday": "Mon","precip": "10"},{"low": "76","high": "82","skycodeday": "9","skytextday": "Light Rain","date": "2018-07-31","day": "Tuesday","shortday": "Tue","precip": "80"},{"low": "79","high": "86","skycodeday": "4","skytextday": "T-Storms","date": "2018-08-01","day": "Wednesday","shortday": "Wed","precip": "100"}]}]

result[0].forecast.forEach(forecast => console.log(forecast.date, "low: ", forecast.low, "high: ", forecast.high))
```

Answer (score 0):

For weather-js library is not possible to achieve what you want, because this library does not expose any other API, it has just one "find".

What I would suggest for you to achieve the desired result are:

- You can have a good contribution to the library, may just create a pull request for your changes.
- You can have a copy on your local env. and just add or edit the results.
- The last that will solve fast and easy your problem is just to use JS transform methods like here.

```js
weather2.find({
    search: location,
    degreeType: 'F'
}, function (err, result) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    result = result.map((item) => item.current.temperature);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: when i input this the terminal spat out an error saying "result.map" is not a function

Comment: I am not sure about your result format right now, by the example you provided this is of type array, so the map is working with arrays. If you are not familiar with the map function would be good if you will learn it will help you.

Comment: I found out that your function params does not match to the weather-js example, this should be result => err, current => result, I will update my snippets

Answer (score 0):

***Quick Answer:***

```
result[1].current.temperature
// do this so you can access the temperature
```

**Hey, If you would like to get the specific temperature, then this is possible.**
I suggest not making it a JSON as that will not help and just take memory.
To explain this, you need to know that this is an array, so you first specify which part. Let's say 0 since you want the name of a user's location. After that you do `.location.name` to specify.